# How do I label Circuitikz resistor R1 with the value below and V1 above

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I use Circuitikz to make a circuit and wanted to make resistor with + V1 - above and R1 with the value below like in the picture. The code I use ended up clumping the R1 and 47 Value instead of the R1 going below the 47. Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[shape=ground]{}
(0,0) to [V, invert, l=$V$, a = $5V$ ] (0,3)
(0,3) to [cspst, i = $I_1$ ] (2,3)
(2,3) to [R, v^=$V_1$, l_=$R_1$, a = 47<\ohm>] (5,3)
(5,3) to [R, l =$R_1$, a = 100<\ohm>] (5,0)
(5,0) -- (0,0);     
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{}
\label{}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the `circuitikz` builtin `l2` options (see pag. 175 of the manual, "Stacked (two line) label"), although [Zarko's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657865/38080) is more general.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mmm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw   (0,0) node[shape=ground]{}
        (0,0)   to [V, invert, l=$V$, a = $5V$ ] (0,3)
                to [cspst, i = $I_1$ ] (2,3)
                to [R, v^=$V_1$, l2_ = \SI{47}{\ohm} and $R_1$, l2 halign=c] (5,3)
                (5,3)   to [R, v^=$V_2$, l2_ = \SI{100}{\ohm} and $R_2$, l2 halign=c] (5,0)
                to [short,-*] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although it seems a bit tight to me, I'd go with

```
      to [R, v^=$V_1$, l_ = {$R_1=\SI{47}{\ohm}$}] (5,3)
```

to obtain

[image]

Comment: +1! I see, that I need to read circuitikz package documentation again :-)

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

With help of `makecell` and `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mmm]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw   (0,0) node[shape=ground]{}
        (0,0)   to [V, invert, l=$V$, a = $5V$ ] (0,3)
                to [cspst, i = $I_1$ ] (2,3)
                to [R, v^=$V_1$, a = \makecell{\SI{47}{\ohm}\\  $R_1$}] (5,3)
        (5,3)   to [R, v^=$V_2$, a = \makecell{\SI{100}{\ohm}\\ $R_2$}] (5,0)
                to [short,-*] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Without `makecell`: `bipole annotation style={align=center}` (either after `to[` or as an option to the enclosing scope).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbelm thank you very much for inbfo!

Comment: @JayBirds Consider accepting the answer (click on the large tick mark below the voting buttons) if it solves your problem. This will help others to easily identify which answer solves the question best.